# Uploading file throws No signature of method exception (in getFile() method)

Tags: grails

Im trying to upload a file, and store it in a file. This is the code in the GSP:

```
<g:form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"  action="update">
<input type="file" name="cv" id="cv"/>
<g:actionSubmit action="upload" name="upload" value="Upload" />
</g:form>
```

In the Controller:

```
def upload(){
def f = request.getFile('cv')
InputStream file = f.inputStream
byte[] bytes = file.bytes
println('bytes: '+bytes)
}
```

As I say in the title, i got an exception here. Any help? Thanks.

EDIT (Full Stacktrace, by request):

```
Error 500: Internal Server Error

URI
/com.publidirecta.azafatas/azafataCertificada/index
Class
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException
Message
No signature of method:org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper.getFile() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [cv] Possible solutions: getXML(), getPart(java.lang.String), getAt(java.lang.String), getAt(java.lang.String), getLocale(), getJSON()

Around line 1158 of grails-app/controllers/com/publidirecta/AzafataCertificadaController.groovy

1155:           def upload(){
1156:       println("Acci√≥n upload. Params: "+params)
1157:       Azafata aza=Azafata.findByUsername(params.user)
1158:       def f = request.getFile('cv')
1159:       InputStream file = f.inputStream
1160:       byte[] bytes = file.bytes
1161:               }


Trace

    Line | Method
->> 1158 | upload  in AzafataCertificadaController.groovy
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    886 | runTask in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|    908 | run . . in     ''
^    680 | run     in java.lang.Thread
```

Comment: I have tried the code and it works for me, don't see anything wrong there.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong, neither, but the exception keeps happening. Grails version issue, maybe? Im on 2.0.4

Comment: maybe try 'grails clean'

Comment: Please, provide full stacktrace to be sure what happens here.

Comment: It could be a config issue, here are a few tips that may help: http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPSPRINGSECURITYCORE-191

Comment: I have checked the config.groovy, and my grails.web.disable.multipart is set to false.

Comment: @Fustigador did you ever solve this? Having the same exact issue here?

Comment: @Aaron, I can't remember. I asked this almost three years ago, and I can't even remember if I managed to solve it. Sorry buddy...

Comment: You can check the answer below, anyway...

Comment: @Fustigador thanks anyway, i know it was long time ago :) answer below didn't seem to work either :(

Comment: Best of lucks my friend

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your request is not treated as a MultiPartRequest. Do something like this:

```
MultipartRequest multipartRequest =  request as MultipartRequest
  if(multipartRequest){
    MultipartFile attachmentFile = multipartRequest.getFile("attachment_file".toString())
    if (attachmentFile) {
        -- copy it ---
    }
  }
```